# Symfony 5.1 Forms - Validation Error with CollectionType: This form should not contain extra fields - not working with PHP 8.2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony5, php-8.1

I have a form like this:

```
class AssignmentType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('ref')
            ->add('rate')
            ->add('costs')
            ->add('notice', TextareaType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'attr' => ['class' => 'summernote'],
            ])
            ->add('documents', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => DocumentType::class,
                'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'required' => false,
                'label' => false,
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Assignment::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And another Form Type like this:

```
class DocumentType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('file', FileType::class, [
                'label'     => false,
                'required'  => true,
                'constraints' => [
                    new File(),
                ],
            ]);

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Document::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

So one assignment can have many documents.
DOM is like this:

```
<div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" id="assignment_documents_0_file" name="assignment[documents][0][file]" class="custom-file-input">
    <label for="assignment_documents_0_file" lang="de" class="custom-file-label"></label>
</div>
```

But the form contains erros - `$form->isValid()` **returns false.**
The error is:

> This form should not contain extra fields.

The Entity **Assignment** has the following entry for **documents**:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Document::class, mappedBy="assignment", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 * @Expose
 */
private Collection $documents;
```

What is wrong here?

**HINT:**
It seems to be a problem with updating PHP 7.4 to PHP 8.1 or PHP 8.2
But I dont see the issue here.
After I downgrading PHP to 7.4 it works - form is valid.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved with Symfony 5.4.
It works with Symfony 5.1 and PHP 7.4 OR with Symfony 5.4 and PHP 8.1. or 8.2

So it was an incompatibility with Symfony and PHP Version.
Perhaps it would also work with PHP 8.1 / 8.2 and Symfony 5.2